# Should we encourage answers to have tl;dr sections?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

This idea just came to my mind. It might be bad...

When browsing Stack Overflow, I see some answers that have "TL;DR" sections which summarize the whole answer. I find these really useful because sometimes I'm in a hurry to find answers. And finally, I found a seemingly helpful one, but it's *super* long. I just can't be bothered to read through that. Wouldn't it be nice to just read a "TL;DR" section with one or two sentences? And those who are willing to see the explanation, can read the rest?

Answers on Stack Overflow not only contain answers but also *explanations* and *elaborations*. The *answer* part of the answer might not appear in the first paragraph of the answer so people who are in a hurry need to read through all the explanations (which they might not care) to get the answer. This decreases the efficiency of people.

I'm suggesting that we show a message when the answer exceeds some number of characters, saying that

> Your answer is a little long. Please consider adding a summary.

Note that this is only *encourages* the answerer, not *forces*. The answerer can choose not to add a summary.

Benefits:

- People in a hurry can get answers faster and more efficiently
- People who are unable to write *organized* answers get a chance to help people understand their unorganized answers
- When people are summarizing their answers, they might reread their answers and find spelling and grammatical errors. This can improve the quality of answers.
- Decrease the chance of misunderstanding

Comment: Why should there be a summary? Especially given that many of the questions on here contain code, a summary, in my mind, would often lead to more noise. If someone writes an incredibly long winded answer, then that's their prerogative. The voting system should sort out whether or not their long windedness is justified.

Comment: So we would have to have a section explicitly marked "Summary" or (ick) "TL;DR"?

Comment: @BilltheLizard if such a thing _does_ create noise, then that would be a good idea to have such a section marked "summary" that is optional, just like the edit summary box.

Comment: Answers  should be concise and well-structured enough not to *need* a tldr. Exceptions exist but are few and far between. Having an official tldr section would reduce the pressure to be as clear as possible in the post itself.

Comment: we should encourage **questions** to ***be*** TL;DR sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found a seemingly helpful one, but it's *super* long

This implies that the question being asked is **too broad** and should be closed. An explanation of why a solution to a problem works is good but people should not be posting entire tutorials or blog posts as answers.

> People who are unable to write organized answers get a chance to help people understand their unorganized answers

If an answer is going to be useful then the entire post should be well organized and understandable, not just two sentences tacked onto the beginning or the end. We don't want to encourage the use of TL;DR sections *instead* of well-written answers.